# Hitting OSStatus error -50 while trying to use automator to connect to betternet vpn

Tags: automator

Hitting OSStatus error -50 while trying to use automator to connect to betternet vpn

[image]

Any other ways e.g. command line method to connect and disconnect from betternet? (e.g. dismissing the ads, using the free version)

Comment: [This page](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-50) indicates many possible reasons for this error.

Comment: Many thanks @IconDaemon. Not sure why it happens. I'll resort to cliclick with hardcoded coordinates for now.